# Probability inequality between subsets of events

Tags: probability

I came across a proof on a statistics book using the following, if$$
S=P(|X|≥\epsilon,|B|≤b)+P(|X|≥\epsilon,|B|≥b)
$$then$$
S≤P\left(\frac{X}{|B|}≥\frac{\epsilon}{b}\right)+P(|B|≥b)
$$
I want to verify if my thinking is correct.

The event $\{\frac{X}{|B|}≥\frac{\epsilon}{b}\}$ is a subset of the event $\{|X|≥\epsilon\cap |B|≤b\}$ which is also true for the second term. The inequality follows since if $X\subset A$ then $$
P(X)≤P(A)
$$
Am I right? I also stated that the second equation are subsets the first by intuition. Is there any need to make this more formal? Or is my line of thinking sufficient?

Comment: Your notation is unusual and ambiguous.  In particular, "$\{A\}$" is a set with one element, $A,$ and so is $\{A\cap B\},$ whose sole element is $A\cap B.$ The first will be a subset of the other if and only if $A\cap B=A,$ which means $A\subseteq B.$  Is that what you intend to convey?  As far as your main question goes, drawing pictures of the events in the $(X,B)$ plane will be a straightforward and likely easy way to see what's going on.

Comment: @whuber thank you for correcting my informal notations. Since many theorems in the book uses inequalities as indicated in my question that are not obvious to see, I want a quick check if the inequalities are due to events being subsets. I will also try to plot the support of the probabilities in my question to check them graphically.

Comment: I'm still puzzled.  Are you sure you are using the notation correctly? By its very definition, $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A,$ not the other way around.  And what is "$P(A,B)$"? One would imagine it's $P(A\cap B),$ but then why not use the latter notation since you are already using it elsewhere?  Moreover, "$B$" looks overloaded: you employ it both as a random variable in the first half of this post and then as an event in the second half.  Very confusing.

Comment: @whuber You are right, your comment made me realize my mistake on the second question and I have also verified that $A\cap B$ is a subset of $A$. Thank you, also, I am used to writing $A,B$ with commas for probability and $A\subset B$ when talking about sets. Maybe because of my other reference books that I thought it was good for it to be written that way

Comment: Once again, I warmly recommend drawing the picture.  It will show that your initial claim about a subset relationship among events is incorrect, but it will show that the union of the two events described in the second formula is a superset of the union of the two events described in the first formula -- so your strategy will indeed work.